# Do .lib files have to be linked every time a project is compiled in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation, linker, static-libraries

Right now in a project I'm working on, compile times are taking very long.

We think it's due to the fact that it is linking all the library files every time it has to recompile the project.

Can we speed this up somehow? Do .libs have to be linked every single time, even when making very small changes?

Comment: The purpose of library files, is exactly that they not should be needed to be compiled every time. So it's just dependent if these small changes affect the libraries as well.

Comment: The lib files aren't getting compiled every time. They are getting linked every time, which is taking very long.

Comment: Linking itself is moderately fast.

Comment: A project solution can constitute of many projects and each project can be linked statically ( lib) or dynamically (dll) and your compile time will be reduced.  If you are using as a single project in your solution with all the source and header files, compiling will be painful.

Comment: Normally the build manager doesn't cause unnecessary builds. .lib files are built by the librarian, not the linker, and it is supposed to be fast. A .lib file is just a simple bag of .obj files with little structure of its own. Are you sure you are not producing dlls?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Linking is **inherently** slow. It cannot be spread across CPU cores, and requires potentially huge tables to be in memory. In addition, more and more code generation is moved into the linker.

Comment: @IInspectable It's usually faster than compiling source.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: For some definition of *"usual"*. I have seen code, where linking took about as much time as compiling it. Heavy use of templates and LTCG can easily lead to a situation like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, object libraries have to be re-linked every time the program compiles.

However, you can make this less painful by making those other projects into DLL projects, which delays the linking until runtime, rather than compile time. That can make the program take a little longer to start up (depending on certain circumstances) and it'll make managing the project output a little more cumbersome, but it'll speed up project compilation by a significant factor.

If you're working with third-party libraries, see if they have DLL versions of the object code (many do), or recompile them as a DLL (if you have the source code), and use those instead. Depending on the library, you may need to make adjustments to your project configuration.